# Trouble getting an app onto Heroku! Application Error: An error occurred in

Tags: heroku

I have been trying to get my app onto Heroku, I was able to push it, then I did the heroku ps:scale web=1, when I did Heroku  open I was greeting with an error message.

```
https://serene-waters-6648.herokuapp.com/ > application error
here is the log output:

jamess-air:mysite jameshemmaplardh$ heroku logs

Your version of git is 2.0.1. Which has serious security vulnerabilities.

More information here: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/23/update_your_git_clients_on_windows_and_os_x

2015-01-23T01:28:38.179841+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by jameshemmaplardh@gmail.com

2015-01-23T01:28:38.179841+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by jameshemmaplardh@gmail.com

2015-01-23T01:42:31.103465+00:00 heroku[api]: Set DATABASE_URL config vars by jameshemmaplardh@gmail.com

2015-01-23T01:42:31.103465+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by jameshemmaplardh@gmail.com

2015-01-23T01:42:31.210960+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by jameshemmaplardh@gmail.com

2015-01-23T01:42:31.210960+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_NAVY resource by jameshemmaplardh@gmail.com

2015-01-23T01:42:31.523763+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by jameshemmaplardh@gmail.com

2015-01-23T01:42:31.621828+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy e0497c1 by jameshemmaplardh@gmail.com

2015-01-23T01:42:31.621828+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by jameshemmaplardh@gmail.com

2015-01-23T01:42:36.935833+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn gettingstarted.wsgi --log-file -`

2015-01-23T01:42:38.038530+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found

2015-01-23T01:42:38.691433+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127

2015-01-23T01:42:38.698984+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

2015-01-23T01:42:38.698153+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I am not sure how to interpret this but from what I understand it should work and my dynos is not blank.

Comment: Do you have `gunicorn` in your `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Yes, I do! I checked what the Haroku is aware of, it knows it has it.